# Constructor DI + Unity+ issue with resolving dependency

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using unity with Prism in xamarin forms.

I have created Interface with name **IDSMobileNaviation**

and Created a service where i have implemented interface  like this

```
public class DSMobileNaviationService: IDSMobileNaviation
```

after i have register this in **App.xaml.cs** like this

```
 protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterType<IDSMobileNaviation,DSMobileNaviationService>();

    }
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
 public class ViewBPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    #region Private variables
    private readonly IDSMobileNaviation _navigationService;

    #endregion
    public ViewBPageViewModel(IDSMobileNaviation navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

When i try to use ViewBPageViewModel i got error

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "DSMobile.ViewModels.ViewBPageViewModel", name = "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: Resolving parameter "navigationService" of constructor DSMobile.ViewModels.ViewBPageViewModel(DSMobile.Interfaces.IDSMobileNaviation navigationService).
>
> Exception is: InvalidCastException - Specified cast is not valid.
>
> ---
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving DSMobile.ViewModels.ViewBPageViewModel,(none)
>
> Resolving parameter "navigationService" of constructor DSMobile.ViewModels.ViewBPageViewModel(DSMobile.Interfaces.IDSMobileNaviation navigationService)

am i missing something ? Suggestions are most welcome

Comment: Please show the part where you declare the unity Container?

Comment: I am using prism packages for xamarin 1)Prism.Core 2)Prism.Forms 3)Prism.Unity.Forms   and my app is like   public partial class App : PrismApplication

Comment: Does the `DSMobileNaviationService` have any dependencies?

Comment: No . it has no dependency

Comment: In Prism.Forms navigationService is a 'reserved' keyword, as INavigationService from Prism is injected into any parameter with that name. If you rename your constructor parameter name, it should work